Insert empty items into chart series with VBA
Context/purpose: I am making a filter tool to get rid of certain datapoints for a chart (e.g. exclude values lower than 50), for which I have a userform to select and input the filter features and then see a preview of the chart before committing to overwriting the source data. I want to have the filtered out points to show up as gaps by using the graph feature "Show empty cells as gaps".
Currently I read in the x and y values from the excel file into arrays, and I apply the filters to the arrays for making the preview charts. The problem is I cannot find a solution to have blank items, as every trial I do ends up as a 0 integer and gets plotted (my arrays are variants).
Tried methods for the blank items:
arrData(i) = ""
arrData(i) = "na()"
arrData(i) = "Empty"

Is there a way to insert blanks via the array, or is the fact that I am using an array as a source imposing the limitation?

How would you like to see the chart having empty points in its series? I cannot imagine it (visually). Series make sense only for serial numbers... To have empty array elements is simple. In 2D array (arr) using arr(3, 1) = "" will clear the content of the element from row 3, first column. But wouldn't it be better to simple eliminate the respective points from the array? Then, showing the code you try would be easier for us to understand what you really try doing and you increase your chances to be helped. I see that your question has already voted down. Because of that, I think...

Thanks for the feedback! I want to utilize the "Show empty cells as gaps" feature of the chart, but I never get to the outcome that would be equivalent to an empty cell with an array as input, as it just fills up with the integer 0 in each case. If I would eliminate the whole array element, then: I would not get a gap, and I would have a more difficult option to overwrite the initial data

Don't write a string like "Empty" to the array - Excel will try to convert the string into a number, and (as this fails) will get the value 0. Try arrData(i) = Empty. Empty is a special value that signals that a Variant variable has no value at all.

Credit to @FunThomas:
Special value of Empty (without quotations) of a Variant item evaluates to:

an empty cell instead if recipient is Range (cell);
the value of 0 if recipient is the numeric variable or expression;
the empty text ("") if recipient is the string variable or expression.

